# Is there a way to set the initial value for React Google Places AutoComplete?

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

Using this library - https://tintef.github.io/react-google-places-autocomplete/docs/ -I have -

```
  <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      apiKey={'someKey'}
      autocompletionRequest={{
          componentRestrictions: {
              country: ['uk']
          }
      }}
      selectProps={{
          value: address,
          onChange: (o) => {
              let placeId = o["value"]["place_id"];
              setAddress(o);
              formik.setFieldValue("googlePlaceId", placeId);
          }
      }}
  />
```

What do I need to pass as the value of "address" for there to be an initial value?

I've tried {label: "some address", place_id: "ChIJNYiUp8ROeEgRikq4Ws76OpU"} and passing the object returned by using the utility geocodeByPlaceId.  The former works in so far has it shows the label in the input field upon initialisation but it appears broken.  For example when I try and delete the value with backspace my react app crashes with this error in the console -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'place_id' of undefined
    at Object.getOptionValue (index.es.js:30)
    at cr (index.es.js:30)
    at eval (index.es.js:30)
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at lr (index.es.js:30)
    at or (index.es.js:30)
    at eval (index.es.js:30)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at rr (index.es.js:30)
    at eval (index.es.js:30)
```

Comment: I think it's helpful for you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776697/react-native-google-places-autocomplete-give-it-a-value-rather-than-just-default/48942132)

Comment: The answer is too old.  The library has moved to version 3 since then.

Answer (score 2):

This is best achieved following the docs of React-Select as suggested by the creator.
But to achive what you want to do, you'll need React State.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from "react-google-places-autocomplete";

const Places = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  //our default data

  useEffect(() => {
    data === "" ? setData("") : setData(data.label);
  }, [data]);
  // updating our default data

  return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_API_KEY}
      autocompletionRequest={{
        componentRestrictions: {
          country: ["ng"], //to set the specific country
        },
      }}
      selectProps={{
        defaultInputValue: data, //set default value
        onChange: setData, //save the value gotten from google
        placeholder: "Start Destination",
        styles: {
          input: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#222222",
          }),
          option: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#222222",
          }),
          singleValue: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            color: "#222222",
          }),
        },
      }}
      onLoadFailed={(error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Places;
```

We use useEffect to update the defualt value we set on condition that we are getting an actual value. If we're not getting actual value, we're not saving it.

Comment: For some reason setting the `value` and `defaultValue` did nothing for me. Setting the placeholder worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly the documentation for this library refers one to the documentation for another, react-select.

This is now my how my component looks -

```
                            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                                apiKey={''}
                                autocompletionRequest={{
                                    componentRestrictions: {
                                        country: ['uk']
                                    }
                                }}
                                selectProps={{
                                    defaultInputValue: formik.status["addressLabel"],
                                    isClearable: true,
                                    value: address,
                                    onChange: (o) => {
                                        let placeId = "";
                                        if(o){
                                            placeId = o["value"]["place_id"];
                                        }
                                        setAddress(o);
                                        formik.setFieldValue("googlePlaceId",placeId);
                                    }
                                }}
                            />
```

So in a higher component I have -

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState();
```

And the default initial value is set like this (using formik) -

```
                            <Formik
                                initialValues={initialValues}
                                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                                // validationSchema={{}}
                                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                                    submitHandler(values, actions)
                                }}
                                initialStatus={{
                                    addressLabel: addressLabel
                                }}
                            >
                                {
                                    formik => {
                                        return (
                                            <Form formik={formik} {...formProps} />
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the address as a text to googlePlacesinput.

You can take a look at how i went about it in this post...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77081486/15315728

Answer (score 0):

I solved doing like that:

```
import { usePlacesWidget } from 'react-google-autocomplete'

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';



const { ref, autocompleteRef } = usePlacesWidget({
    apiKey: googleApiKey,
    options: {
      types: ['address']
    },
    onPlaceSelected: (place) => {
      console.log(place)
      const latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
      const longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
      
      console.log(latitude, longitude)
      setFormState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        location: place.formatted_address || "",
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude
      }));
    }
  });

  useEffect(()=> {
    if (!isEditing && ref.current !=null)
    {
      const inputElement = ref.current as HTMLInputElement;
      if (initialForm?.location)
      {
        inputElement.value = initialForm?.location
        inputElement.click()
      }
    }
  }, [isEditing, ref])
```

and later using it

```
<TextField 
 label="Location"
 inputRef={ref}
 disabled={!isEditing}
 >
</TextField>
```

isEditing and initialForm are setted from the parent component to the child, basically the useEffect looks for changes in ref and isEditing, if isEditing is false then there is initialForm.location value and just interact with the HTMLInputElement (ref.current) set the value and click it (the click here is absolutely necessary to correctly trigger the input label of MUI TextField to behave correctly). Sorry about really busy day I can't post a good reproducable snippet right now.